# Foreign Key binding to object

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-core, entity-framework-6

I have some model created, which is supposed to store GUIDs (strings) as identifiers and I want the class that has a foreign key with it to also have the object to be accessed. I remembered while using LinqToSql was pretty simple, but now I'm running into some troubles with EF.

I have tried putting the object as virtual but I think I have to do something on the DbContext, because when I try to create the migration it fails due to recursion limit (I guess this is due to making sort of circular references).

For example, I have the following classes:

```cs
public class Calculation
{
    [Required]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public Guid UserId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("UserId")]
    public virtual User User { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Title { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public Guid CausativeId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("CausativeId")]
    public virtual Causative Causative { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public bool Active { get; set; }
}
```

```cs
public class Causative
{
    [Required]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Document { get; set; }

    public virtual Calculation Calculation { get; set; }
}
```

The idea is that the Calculation knows who is it's Causative, but I also want to be able to do it the other way around (this was something pretty useful on LinqToSql), if this is not possible, just automatically filling the Causative property with the corresponding data without the need of explicitly making another call to the database.

Should I do something in the DbContext instance? I have this in place:

```cs
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
{
    base.OnModelCreating(builder);

    builder.Entity<Calculation>().HasOne(calculation => calculation.Causative).WithOne(causative => causative.Calculation);
}
```

I'm sure I'm doing something wrong, but I'm not sure what.

Thanks in advice!

Answer (score 0):

For that model you created, you should change this one for OnModelCreating:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Causative>()
            .HasOne(p => p.Calculation)
            .WithOne(i => i.Causative)
            .HasForeignKey<Calculation>(b => b.CausativeId);
```

and this is for one to many if you have  `IEnumerable<Calculation>` in  Causative:

```
 modelBuilder.Entity<Calculation>()
                .HasOne(p => p.Causative)
                .WithMany(b => b.Calculation);
```

Comment: Thanks much! So in the case of one to many, how does it knows that the CausativeId is present in Calculation?

Comment: I dont understand clearly, but you have CausativeId and navigation property  in Calculation and you can know about it!

Answer (score 0):

I think that you just need to replace this line:

```
public virtual Calculation Calculation { get; set; }
```

with this:

```
public virtual List<Calculation> Calculations { get; set; }
```

or this:

```
public virtual ICollection<Calculation> Calculations { get; set; }
```

this will create for you the right navigation property and FK